# Converting double to string in C++ gives strange characters (Chinese characters?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion, tostring

I am trying to convert two double values into strings in C++ so that I can use TRACE to view them in my output window. I am using Visual Studio 2017. Here is my main code:

```
double distance = 3.0;
double secondsPassed = 10.0;
TRACE(L"Hello!\n");
TRACE(L"distance = %s seconds passed: %s \n",
    std::to_string(distance).c_str(), std::to_string(secondsPassed).c_str());
```

This is the definition of my TRACE function:

```
void TRACE(TCHAR *format, ...)
{
    TCHAR buffer[1000];

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    wvsprintf(buffer, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);

    OutputDebugString(buffer);
}
```

This is what shows up in my output window:

```
Hello!
distance = ⸳〰〰〰 time: 〱〮〰〰0찀쳌쳌
```

I'm not sure why the two double values are not being converted into the strings "3.0" and "10.0". Instead I get these weird characters! I apologize if they are not Chinese characters as I mentioned in the title - I only know English

Any suggestions or comments would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a convoluted way of doing things.  Instead of converting the values to strings so that they match the `%s` formatting directive, why not leave them as `double`s and use a `%f` directive?

Comment: the temporary std::string is gone, if you assign to a const reference the temporary lifetime is guarantee to survive, however, TRACE is a variadic function. Create the string before the TRACE will solve the problem

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi doesn't that string only get destructed after the call to the function to which it's the argument?

Comment: @stijn it is not the std::string the input of the function, but the underlying pointer

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: The temporary strings will be destroyed at the end of the full expression, that is when `TRACE()` returns, so the underlying pointer will still be valid when used.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `TRACE` macro expects wide strings but you are passing narrow ones: look at the `w` in function `wvsprintf()`.

Use `std::to_wstring()` and it should work.

Alternatively you can use `%hs` to tell that your arguments are narrow strings. Or you can change the macro and make it call `vsprintf()`.

Comment: %hs instead of %S could be mentioned.

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh, yes, I didn't know that. `%hs` is better than `%S` because it will always be a `const char *` no matter the UNICODE options, matching `std::string`.